# Building the Go SWIG example code

Tags: go, swig

I'm trying to build the example SWIG bindings that come with Go. The files I'm looking at are located in misc/swig/callback.

Are there instructions on how to build this example? I tried following the directions here:
http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Go.html
but the code generated by SWIG doesn't seem to compile with g++ (since it uses a C++ library ) and doesn't compile with g++ (with multiple compilation errors).

Has anyone built this example successfully?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example,

```
$ export GOPATH=$HOME/gopath
$ cd $GOPATH/src/swig/callback
$ go clean
$ go install -v
swig/callback
$
```

Since you say you had problems with g++, do you have everything installed for g++? For example,

```
$ sudo apt-get install g++ g++-multilib libstdc++6
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, and now I'm getting:

`/tmp/go-build130356132/callback/_obj/callback.go:22: _swig_fnptr redeclared in this block
 previous declaration at ./callback.go:22`

Which seems strange since the first file looks like a temporary file generated during the build

Comment: Update: this works now. I had to delete the temporary `callback.go` file that was generated by SWIG.